# How to do Log Base 2 in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to calculate password entropy in ColdFusion (I know I could do it in JavaScript, but I like everything to work on the server as well as the client). In order to do so I need to be able to do a Log Base 2.

ColdFusion has a Log() function for a natural log and a Log10 for a Log Base 10, but I don't see any function that lets me determine the base for the Log.

I assume that I need to drop down to Java to do this, but I am not sure the best way to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you do `log(x)/log(2)` this is equivalent to log base 2 of x